# saving a Cookie in javascript with the current url saves it with double quotes in PHP $_COOKIE

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

I'm using jQuery Cookie to save a cookie and then access it in PHP.

```
$( document ).on( 'click', '#ai1ec-calendar-view .ai1ec-load-event', function( e ) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.cookie.raw = true;
    $.cookie( 'ai1ec_calendar_url', document.URL );
    window.location.href = this.href;
} );
```

but if i dump it in PHP i get double quotes added as you can see from the following picture. What's happening?

[image]

Comment: Can you do a `console.log(document.URL)`?

Comment: @MarcelKorpel i guess the problem is that Cookies are stringified by jQuery.Cookie.

Comment: Can you test it with native JavaScript cookie functions?

Comment: You're correct, have a look at https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/blob/master/jquery.cookie.js#L65 (this is also why I hate 3rd party code I don't understand).

Comment: @MarcelKorpel he says that stringifing is required by RFC2068 didn't know that. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: Who says that? I flipped through [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) but can't find anything that implies that.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is related to the fact that cookie string should be quoted and thus jQuery Cookie was adding the double quotes. The solution in PHP is to use json_decode

```
$href = json_decode( $_COOKIE['ai1ec_calendar_url'] );
```